# Typescript/React/MUI use custom color on Button component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I trying to apply custom color to Button component but I getting error. What is possible solution for that?

I made module module augmentation like in docs but problem still remain:

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors

Message:
`Button.d.ts(34, 5): The expected type comes from property 'color' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ElementType<any>; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; ... 10 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'`

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ff0000',
    },
    play: {
      main: '#ffffff',
      contrastText: 'black'
    },
    moreInfo: {
      main: '#6c6c6e',
      contrastText: 'white'
    },
    tonalOffset: 0.2,
  },
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1200,
      xl: 1536,
    },
  },
});
```

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Palette {
        play?: Palette['primary'];
        moreInfo?: Palette['primary'];
    }
    interface PaletteOptions {
        play?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
        moreInfo?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they should be optional? Also, include the error message in your question.

Comment: You need to extend the interface: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/

Answer (score 8):

For MUI 5.11.14
i had to add `true`

```js
declare module "@mui/material" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    myCoolColour: true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, after hours of searching, thank you! I wish this would've been more obvious in the docs, as I never knew this existed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that adding colors to the palette in MUI (even when you augment the createPalette module as you have here) does not automatically add them to the Button's available colors.  In order to allow the Button's Color prop, you also need to extend an additional interface:

```
declare module '@mui/material' {
    interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
        play,
        moreInfo,
    }
}
```

You will need to do this on a per-component basis. I've also extended createPalette in a slightly different way, but yours may also be correct:

```
import "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
    interface PaletteOptions {
        play?: PaletteColorOptions,
        moreInfo?: PaletteColorOptions,
    }

    interface Palette {
        play: PaletteColor,
        moreInfo: PaletteColor,
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to change `ButtonsPropsColorOverrides` to `ButtonPropsColorOverrides`

Comment: Thanks @YahyaFati, updated my solution.